# Как получить внешний IP при помощи Java

Tags: java, ip, геолокация

Пишу бот для Telegram, встал вопрос определения геолокации по IP. Как я понял на Java это реализуется только с помощью запроса к какому либо серверу, но ведь он может перестать функционировать. Есть ли методы обхода данной проблемы?

Comment: хранить базу геолокации локально и искать в ней

Comment: Этот вариант не удовлетворяет?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415851/best-way-to-get-geo-location-in-java

Comment: @ILMare насколько я понял, данная библиотека содержит готовую базу? Если так то вполне подойдет

Comment: @ILMare  Посмотрел примеры, там тоже требуется указывать IP

Comment: Как ты достаешь адрес при внешнем запросе я так и не нашел. Все советуют обрашаться на подобные сервисы. 

`http://myexternalip.com/raw`

Но если ты нашел метод получения внешнего адреса из коннекшина можно попробовать обратится к днс адресу. 

`List<String> servers = ResolverConfiguration.open().nameservers();
if(servers.size()>0) {
Socket echoSocket = new Socket(servers.get(0), 53);`

Дело в том что внешний адрес без запроса вряд ли возможно определить в случаях когда машина находится в интернете не на прямую(не через nat).

Comment: Может быть ситуация когда машина имеет доступ к интернету по  нескольким путям.

Comment: Если один сервер перестал функционировать, то можно переключиться на другой. И так далее.